# How to cache a JSONP response while using WinJS.xhr?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

Using the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function it is possible to [cache a JSONP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892671/how-can-i-guarantee-that-an-ajax-response-will-be-cached) by utilizing its `cache` & `isModified` properties.

The `WinJS.xhr` function doesn't appear to have any direct properties. I've seen a lot of questions asking for a way to DISABLE caching. I need a way for a JSONP response to be **always cached**.

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work -

```
WinJS.xhr({ 
    url: URL_that_returns_JSONP_response,
    headers: {
        "Cache-control": "Public"
    } })
    .done(
...
```

When I check the HTTP response status with Fiddler, I see that the status code is still 200 & the response is not cached. How can I enable caching of JSONP response while using WinJS.xhr?

Comment: You realize that you can use jquery in WinJS projects just fine?

Answer (score 0):

Becuse a JSONP request works by creating a <script> element with its src attribute set to the request URL. You cannot add custom headers to the HTTP request sent by a <script> element.